# How trigger a reference value change from another sheet in a cell ? [google sheet script]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It is possible to trigger a value change in a cell, where the value is a reference from another sheet?

With `onEdit()` I just get the cell of the referenced cell.

As example:

Sheet A, cell A1, the value is: `=SheetB!A2` (from another sheet)

How I can trigger now a new value in cell `A1`?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You have to call the other Sheet, for example:</s>

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(“id of your main sheet”);
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(“id of the other sheet);

var valueA2 = sheet2.getRange(“A2”).getValue();
var valueA1 = sheet1.getRange(“A1”).setValue(valueA2);
```

Since the A1 value is `=SheetB!A2`, I assume both of the sheets share the same ID. The onEdit() function works on the entire sheet, unless you specify the name of the Sheet in a condition. The problem is you want to trigger an event if the A1 value from SheetA gets an update from SheetB, which is redundant as you are already editing the SheetB, so the onEdit() function will ignore the SheetA being updated. You should trigger the event when the SheetB A2 cell is updated, unless you want to do something very specific when updating the SheetA.

Comment: ty, but that's not what I mean. I want to trigger a change on a referenced cell.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, could you be more specific? What I understand now is you have a cell getting the value from another sheet, and you want to trigger something when that value is updated, am I right?

Comment: I see. I'm editing my answer as my comment doesn't fit here.